# Lagrange multiplier method failure

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to solve the following problem, and I think the solution manual's conclusion is wrong:

Find the extrema of f subject to the stated constraints:
$$f(x,y) = x$$, subject to $$x^2 + 2y^2 = 3$$

Obviously, the Lagrange multipliers method failed. The solution manual concluded that $f$ has no maximum or minimum value in the given set $U$, but by theorem, since we study the function on a closed and bounded set, absolute and minimum values must exist

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the method failed? Maybe you are looking at the wrong solution ?

Comment: This problem is equivalent to asking what are the largest and smallest $ \ x-$coordinates of a point on the ellipse $ \ x^2 + 2y^2 \ = \ 3 \ \ . $   Since the curve is centered on the origin and its semi-minor axis of length $ \  \sqrt3 \ $ lies on the $ \ x-$axis, these coordinate values are $ \ \pm \sqrt3 \ \ . $

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+2y^2=3\}$ is compact and therefore any continuous function defined on it has to have a maximum and a minimum.

And the Lagrange method does *not* fail. Let $g(x)=x^2+2y^2$. The the method leds to the equations$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}1=2\lambda x\\0=4\lambda y\\x^2+2y^2=3.\end{array}\right.$$It follows from the second equality that $\lambda=0$ or that $y=0$. But you cannot have $\lambda=0$, since $2\lambda x=1$. So, $y=0$, and therefore $x=\pm\sqrt3$. The maximum is then $\sqrt3$, which is attained at $\left(0,\sqrt3\right)$, and the minimum is $-\sqrt3$, which is attained at $\left(0,-\sqrt3\right)$.

All this was simply meant to show that the method works. Of course, it is easy and more natural to solve the problem without it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I was looking at the wrong exercise. I meant to write $$f(x,y) = x-y$$ constrained by $$x^2 - y^2 = 2$$

Comment: Of course that the method of Lagrange multipliers will not work then. The restriction of $f$ to that region (which is not compact) is unbounded, both above and below.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir